# pandas dataframe exponential decay summation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe,

```
[[1, 3],
[4, 4],
[2, 8]...
]
```

I want to create a column that has this:

```
1*(a)^(3)   # = x
1*(a)^(3 + 4) + 4 * (a)^4  # = y
1*(a)^(3 + 4 + 8) + 4 * (a)^(4 + 8) + 2 * (a)^8  # = z
...
```

Where "a" is some value.
The stuff: 1, 4, 2, is from column one, the repeated 3, 4, 8 is column 2
Is this possible using some form of transform/apply?

Essentially getting:

```
[[1, 3, x],
[4, 4, y],
[2, 8, z]...
]
```

Where x, y, z is the respective sums from the new column (I want them next to each other)

There is a "groupby" that is being done on the dataframe, and this is what I want to do for a given group

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this should work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3], [4, 4], [2, 8]], columns=['a', 'b'])
a = 42
new_lst = []

for n in range(len(lst)):
    z = 0
    i = 0
    while i <= n:
        z += df['a'][i]*a**(sum(df['b'][i:n+1]))
        i += 1
    new_lst.append(z)
df['new'] = new_lst
```

---

Update:

Saw that you are using pandas and updated with dataframe methods. Not sure there's an easy way to do this with apply since you need a mix of values from different rows. I think this for loop is still the best route.

Comment: will check it out!  no way of vectorizing this somehow though?

Comment: There might be some obscure way but with all your different references to previous values, I'm struggling to think of some way to vectorize it.